# How to select/create a custom field in the REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, sitepages

We currently use the following format to retrieve a list of data from SharePoint Online and it works fine, but how can I do a similar query that returns a different field "as" the `Id` field?

```
https://server/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=<filter criteria 1>
```

I would like to do the equivalent of this if possible?

```
https://server/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/Items?$select=SomeOtherId as Id,Title&$filter=<filter criteria 2>
```

So that the output still says `Id` but the value is what is contained in the `SomeOtherId` field. The database equivalent syntax would be

```
select SomeOtherId as Id,Title ...
```

Or even how to merge two fields as the output field, such as FirstName + Surname as Name?

Is this possible?

Comment: This is not possible using REST APIs. Where are you using the results of api call? You can transform the results in success function.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I currently have to add a [JsonProperty] decorator in the code for each mapping. This works, but I thought SP would have the ability to provide this functionality without me having to loop through all the results.

Comment: No, SP REST API does not provide the functionality to use `as` in `$select` query. check my answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using SharePoint REST APIs. You cannot use `as` in $select query in REST APIs.

After you get results from REST API call, you have to transform results array in `success` function to add new property in results array. You can do it like given below:

```
Results.forEach(function (item) {
  item.SomeOtherId = item.Id;
});
```

OR

```
Results.map(item => ({ ...item, SomeOtherId: item.Id }))
```

**Reference**: [Add property to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922998/add-property-to-an-array-of-objects)